# Why is sometimes async keyword not used with a method suffixed with async?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await

I was reading about health check in asp.net core.

I have seen this code.

```
public class ExampleHealthCheck : IHealthCheck
{
    public Task<HealthCheckResult> CheckHealthAsync(
        HealthCheckContext context,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var healthCheckResultHealthy = true;

        if (healthCheckResultHealthy)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(
                HealthCheckResult.Healthy("A healthy result."));
        }

        return Task.FromResult(
            HealthCheckResult.Unhealthy("An unhealthy result."));
    }
}
```

In the above code the method `CheckHealthAsync` is not marked async. Is it made in such a way to support both synchronous and asynchronous function?

Comment: It doesn't need to be marked async. It returns a `Task` which makes it async to the outside world.

Comment: A method only needs to be marked `async` if it uses the `await` operator. This method does not use the `await` operator.

Comment: @juunas I find your comment confusing. Having Async in the name does not *make* it asynchronous. That's just a naming convention.

Comment: True. It is just a naming convention, used here because a Task is returned.

Comment: @juunas Do you mean wherever a task is returned I should use this naming convention?

Comment: _"Asynchronous methods in TAP include the Async suffix after the operation name for methods that return awaitable types, such as Task, Task<TResult>, ValueTask, and ValueTask<TResult>."_ - [Naming, parameters, and return types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#naming-parameters-and-return-types)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two parts to this answer:

- `Async` suffix is used to satisfy `IHealthCheck` interface requirement. It is just a naming convention (albeit an important one) which has no special meaning in the language itself.
- `async` is not used because method's *implementation* does not need it (i.e. it has no `await`s)

Note that the implementation also uses `Task.FromResult` rather than returning the value directly. This is also done to satisfy the requirements of `IHealthCheck` interface, which is designed to *allow* for implementations to be asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

`async` only allows you to use await, if you're looking for a way to tell if something runs async, a return type of `Task` is your best hint.